Debugging .NET MAUI app targetting iOS in Visual Studio 2022 for Windows
I need to debug the mobile app I developed using .NET MAUI targetting iOS device.
When I run the project, VS 2022 connects successfully to a Mac OS Machine, however, later I receive this error:

the exact error is a symbol not found:
dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin Referenced from: /Users/desytec/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/dotnet (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15) Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib in /Users/desytec/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/dotnet
This occurs when initializing workloads.
Do I have to install something in the mac OS machine?
EDIT:
I have installed a higher version of MacOS:

With this XCode:

That way, I could finally pair the Mac retrieving all devices I could use to debug:

However, when building, I got the following errors:

I have explicitly specified target iOS version to be 11:
In project properties:

And in iOS\info.plist file:


Do I have to install something in the mac OS machine? What is XCode and TargetFramework versions?

My Mac is 10.13 and I have installed XCode for this version... that is, 9.0.1

TargetFramework .net6.net7.net8?

I'm not sure you can use .net7 or .net8 not even .net6 see this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Release-Versions

I had to upgrade my MAC OS, then my XCODE with IOS 17.4. A while ago... Do not remember the exact issue, but I remember some people with old machines being unable to upgrade them, and as it turns out - unable to build anymore.

@MustafaMutasim .NET 8

@H.A.H. it seems I have to upgrade my macOS to 10.15 version if there is no other solution.

I had a really old 2010 Macbook Pro and I had to boot it from an external drive (USB stick) to install an unsupported version of MacOS on it. Then I could install most newer XCODE versions as well and it worked. Be cautious because not all newer MacOS versions will run on that old machine (in case you also have a machine as old as mine).

@MustafaMutasim I have upgraded macOS but other errors occur. Please see the question edit.

Supported platforms for .NET MAUI apps indicates：

.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) apps can be written for the
following platforms:macOS 10.15 or higher.

So if you want to run the .net8 MAUI project, your Mac needs to meet the system version 10.15 or higher.
The macOS 10.13 version is not supported currently, so an error will appear.

I have upgraded macOS but other errors occur. Please see the question edit.

The error message shows that the error is about Linker behavior, you can refer to the explanation of linker behavior in MAUI. In YourProject -> Properties ->iOS -> Build -> Linker behavior,You can try to set Debug for Don't LInk and Release for Link Framework SDKs Only.

I have created a new VM with macOS 14.5 and project was finally built correctly, however, when trying to launch iOS simuslator I get the following error: iOS Simulator: A fatal error occurred while trying to start the server.. I think if that error is shown, iOS app was correctly built, so I can use a physical device to test it, right?

Regarding the startup problem of iOS simulator On Mac, you can check the settings of simulator in Xcode. In addition, if you need to deploy MAUI project to iPhone device, you can refer to Automatic provisioning for iOS apps
